# Adding text before a wildcard in Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Problem:** I want to be able to add text before the wildcard "{id}".

**What I've tried:** I've tried to add the stringified text followed by a plus "+" and then the wildcard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible with security rules.  Wildcard matches must be on an entire path segment.  They can't match a substring of a path segment.

Comment: Understood. I fixed it by instead replacing text in the wildcard inside the function.